# Convert Array to Floats Array with notation Java

Tags: java

Sorry for the title name but this is probably a funny question. i need to have this like it is. I have an array of floats in the format `[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]` i need the array to be represented like `[10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f, 50.0f]`. I have tried using array List to convert and add the notation and convert back.. but no matter what i try, i still get a float array that looks like a double. Any ideas Please?

even tried something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> valuelist = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int z = 0; z < mValues.length; z++){
    valuelist.add(Float.toString(mValues[z]) + "f");
}  //its fine here but later changes

Object[] objarray2 = valuelist.toArray();
String[] stringfloat  = Arrays.copyOf(objarray2, objarray2.length, String[].class);              
float[] myfloat = new float[stringfloat.length];
for(int j =0; j< myfloat.length; j++){
    //myfloat[j] = Float.parseFloat(stringfloat[j]);
    myfloat[j] = Float.valueOf(stringfloat[j]);
}
```

Comment: That will be a `String` array , with float literal you need to hardcode the array elements.

Comment: Can I ask please why would you need it?

Comment: `float` and `double` data types are both floating point numbers, the only difference is their range. It is normal that floats look like double.

Comment: @erencan: their range and precision!

Comment: `10.0` and `10.0f` is the same number, you only need the `f` in your source code to distinguish between `float` and `double`. The `String` representation of a `float` does not contain the trailing `f`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jlordo `float` and `double` both use [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) representation. their precisions are different because different range of precisions fit into 32 bits and 64 bits.

Comment: @erencan: That is correct. In your prev. comment you wrote that the range is the only difference, but (as you know also wrote) the precision is also different.

Comment: @jlordo their precision are different as a result of their range.

Comment: @erencan: with range, do you mean the distance from `-MAX_VALUE` to `MAX_VALUE` or the number of bits?

Answer (score 0):

`f` is used to tell the **compiler** that treat this as float number. If you want your array in this format use an array of string and append `f` in each element

As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` (§4.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original array where members are float and just create a "String myToString()" method to print it like you want, with the +"f".
I mean, create a personalized method to print the array like you want it to appear.

I assume you just want the print out of the array of float to "appear" with a final f.
The representation in the machine of the number will not change with an f  at the end or not.
The final f in the ***string*** is useful when parsing a number, so you the parser knows which kind of number it is, if you already do not tell it.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
myfloat[j] = Float.valueOf(stringfloat[j]);
```

Here's `Float.valueOf(String)`:

```
public static Float valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException 
{
    return new Float(FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).floatValue())
}
```

As you can see, it returns a `Float`, which is created through `Float(float)` constructor, which is simply:

```
public Float(double value) 
{
   this.value = (float) value;
}
```

The `readJavaFormatString(String)` converts the `String` to a `double`, and `.floatValue()` converts the `double`, wrapped in a `FloatingDecimal` to a `float`, which is passed to the above constructor.
So, im short, you do have a `float`.

NB:

```
float num1 = XYZ;
float num2 = XYZf;
```

Despite the different notation, `num1` and `num2` compile to the same bytecode (where `XYZ` are some numbers, say 123); however, you cannot make an assignment of a number ending in an `f` to say an `int`.  Additionally, if you try to put an `int` into a float, you do not need the `f` at the end, but if your number has any numbers to the right of the radix, you need to append the `f` so that it will compile with a `possible loss of precision` error.

Also, you really shouldn't be using `float` unless there's a good reason to do so, especially if you're planning to use `==` for comparison; instead, use `double`.  `float` and `double` are essentially the same thing, except that `double` is 64-bits, whereas a `float` is 32-bits, so a `double` is more precise.